# How to adjust the italic font of numbers in the theorem environment?

Tags: fonts, theorems

In the theorem environment, the font style of text is in italics, which includes numbers. However, the default italic syle of numbers appears to be ornamental penmanship. I'd like to adjust to comfortable italics.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,lineno}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Any simple 1-planar graph with minimum degree 7 has at least 24 vertices of degree 7.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The italic style of 24 and 7 in the picture below is what I expected.

[image]

I'd like to know how to adjust the digital italic style font in theorem environment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since 1 is used in its numeric meaning, it should be upright as all other numbers (when used in their numeric meaning), so `$1$`

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I found  that some authors use 1, but some others  use $1$. I was confused by the different ways of dealing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're seeing is just the italic Computer Modern font. It sounds like you would prefer if numbers were slanted rather than italic.

To do that, you could use `\textsl` to use a slanted font for numbers only. Then, the result looks like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,lineno}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Any simple \textsl{1}-planar graph with minimum degree \textsl{7} has at least \textsl{24} vertices of degree \textsl{7}.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is to change the whole `plain` theorem style (or to define a new one) so that the body of the theorem is all slanted. The result looks like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,lineno}
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\slshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Any simple 1-planar graph with minimum degree 7 has at least 24 vertices of degree 7.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```